# Regular Expression program from Predefined character classes

Tags: java, regex, scjp

```
public class RegularExpressionDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("a1b7 @z#");
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.start() + "-------" + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), it says the `.` symbol prints any character then How come the above program doesn't print any thing.

Comment: Because you're escaping the `.` (with a backslash), making it match literal `.`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You double-escaped the dot.

This means you are matching a literal dot, not a wildcard for any character.

Your input does not contain one, hence nothing gets printed.

Change the `Pattern` to `"."`.

Comment: If i don't double escape then it gives error "illegal escape character" at that line

Comment: @kittu `"."`, not `"\."`.

Comment: @kittu what JDK / IDE are you using? That should definitely **not** happen.

Comment: Thanks it works. Actually I shouldn't escape it at all unlike other patterns